# for file picker openFileChooser() method not calling WebChromeClient of Kitkat 4.4

Tags: javascript, android

I have one hi-bride application in which one html page has file picker and i want to load that page in Android webview.

This pickers works well in Device browser but not in webview.

For to support this i am using one hidden method of WebChromeClient which is as below

```
public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType){  
            /**updated, out of the IF **/
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            /**updated, out of the IF **/
            if(boolFileChooser){ //Take picture from filechooser
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);  
                i.setType("image/*");  
                startActivityForResult( Intent.createChooser( i, "Pick File.." ), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE );  
            } else { //Take photo and upload picture
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  "Pic.jpg");
                if(photo.exists())
                    photo.delete();
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
                mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(photo);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERAREQUEST_RESULTCODE);
            }
        }
    // Per Android < 3.0
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg){
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
        }
        //Aftre
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
        }
```

It was working fine till 4.3 but from 4.4 this method is not getting called. 
And they said **https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62220** this has been removed.

**Do anyone knows any alternate way. Please let me know your help will greatly appreciated**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no ways to **openFileChooser** method after 4.3 as google has removed that and they will come up with other way to handle this file chooser stuff in next version (Confirmed by Google engineer).

I moved to hybrid architecture to and write native function for file picker.

Comment: I tried this on HTC One. On it's default browser, I could upload the file with file picker easily. But on my own webview it doesn't invoke. There must be some workaround.

Answer (score 1):

In Android 5.0, they introduced [onShowFileChooser()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onShowFileChooser(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Candroid.net.Uri[]%3E,%20android.webkit.WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams)), with which you can use an input form field in the webview and launch a file chooser to select images and files from the device.

Answer (score -1):

```
Bitmap bitmap;

private static final int READ_REQUEST_CODE = 42;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);

    // Filter to only show results that can be "opened", such as a
    // file (as opposed to a list of contacts or timezones)
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    // Filter to show only images, using the image MIME data type.
    // If one wanted to search for ogg vorbis files, the type would be "audio/ogg".
    // To search for all documents available via installed storage providers,
    // it would be "*/*".
    intent.setType("image/*");

    startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);

}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
    Intent resultData) {

    // The ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT intent was sent with the request code
    // READ_REQUEST_CODE. If the request code seen here doesn't match, it's the
    // response to some other intent, and the code below shouldn't run at all.

    if (requestCode == READ_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        // The document selected by the user won't be returned in the intent.
        // Instead, a URI to that document will be contained in the return intent
        // provided to this method as a parameter.
        // Pull that URI using resultData.getData().
        Uri uri = null;
        if (resultData != null) {
            uri = resultData.getData();

            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),uri);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             ImageView my_img_view = (ImageView ) findViewById (R.id.uploadlayout2);
             my_img_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);                                        
        }
    }
}
```